# Automatically setting the DISPLAY variable

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

At the moment, I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux to use Ubuntu, and Xming to allow me to run graphical applications. I was wondering how I could automatically set the display variable to 0, so that I don't need to run "export DISPLAY=:0" every time I open Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd add it at the end of .login but that may not be executed in WSL so the safest bet is to add it at the end of .profile.

**Edit**

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html
The gist of the startup is .profile is not executed if either .bash_login or .bash_profile exists.  To solve this, add this to the end of .bash_profile if it exists.

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
echo DISPLAY is $DISPLAY
```

Comment: Just pasting that in at the end of the file doesn't work.

Comment: So you pasted it at the end of .profile, closed the wsl window,  started the wsl window and type **echo $DISPLAY** and it gives you a blank line?

Comment: That's exactly what happened

Comment: Check the spelling of DISPLAY in your edit.and make sure there is a blank line after the export statement.

Comment: It's still not setting the variable

Comment: Maybe your .profile is not being executed - add **echo DISPLAY is $DISPLAY** after your export statement.  When you open a new console, it should tell you what the display variable is set to.  If it doesn't display anything, then .profile is not being excecuted.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like .profile is not being executed

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer

Comment: Neither .bash_login or .bash_profile existed, and I think there was something wrong with Ubuntu, since a fresh install of 20.04 LTS is executing .profile just fine.