# Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified on WSL

Tags: firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, environment-variables

Good morning

I run Ubuntu using the Windows Subsystem for Linux on a Win11 equipped laptop, I've recently tried to install firefox and open it through the CLI but, whenever i give the firefox command followed by anything, it just says

```
Error: no DISPLAY variable specified
```

I tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231026/automatically-setting-the-display-variable) guide but it now just says:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using wsl1, wsl2 or wslg? If wsl1 or 2, you need to install an x server on Windows and configure it, then point your DISPLAY variable to it. Otherwise, install wslg. See https://github.com/microsoft/wslg

Comment: Definitely start by reverting the change you made based on the [older answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231026/automatically-setting-the-display-variable).  That question was specifically from someone who already had Ximg installed, which it doesn't sound like you do.  And that shouldn't be needed any longer, at least not under Windows 11.  Can you run the following command in PowerShell and [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1468936/edit) your question to include the results:  `Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object OsName, OsVersion, WindowsUBR` - Thanks!